# how to unistall dropbox from ubuntu?

Tags: apt, nautilus, dpkg, dropbox

```
hemant@HmNt-pc:~$ sudo apt-get remove nautilus-dropbox
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
hemant@HmNt-pc:~$
```

This error comes after I input the following command

```
sudo apt-get remove nautilus-dropbox
```

Can anyone suggest a way around this, please?

Answer (score 2):

From the error message it sounds like another package manager is already running. You will not be able to run apt-get if you have, for example, synaptic package manager open at the same time.

Close out of the other package manager and try again. Or restart to make sure that no other ones are running.

Comment: The one other reason would be that apt-get crashed and somehow did not remove the lock (which is unlikely, but could happen.) Although I think a reboot would resolve that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try and remove it with Synaptic and see if that helps. To install Synaptic type the following:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

After synaptic is installed launch it as the root user as follows:

```
sudo synaptic
```

Once the program opens you should then be able to search for Dropbox and remove the relevant packages.

Comment: Unlikely to succeed - The question states that a lock on the database cannot be created.